# Populating UIPickerView with audio files from documents Directory

Tags: ios, nsarray, uipickerview

I am trying to get the .caf files from a directory and then putting them into a UIPickerView so I can play them when each row is tapped.

So far I have this code but can't figure out how to put files into array.

```
NSString *extension = @"caf";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentsDirectory14 = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Family"];
NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory14 error:&error];
NSMutableArray *cafFiles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [contents count]];

NSString *filename;
for (filename in contents)

    NSLog(@"filename;%@",filename);

{
    if ([[filename pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension])
    {

        [cafFiles  addObject: [NSMutableArray  arrayWithContentsOfFile:[documentsDirectory14 stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]]];
    }
}    

 NSLog(@"jpegFiles;%@",cafFiles );

covers= [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:cafFiles];{
    for (filename in cafFiles);
}
NSLog(@"%@", covers);
```

Can someone help me on this?

Will this then put the names of the files in the picker view if I use covers as the array for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked like you were trying to load the actual audio data, which you don't want for a picker view - you want the names of the files. Try this code instead, which is based on yours:

```
NSString *extension = @"caf";
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *familyDirectory = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Family"];
NSArray *directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:familyDirectory
                                                                        error:NULL];
NSIndexSet *cafFileNameIndexes = [directoryContents indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSString *fileName, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [[fileName pathExtension] isEqualToString:extension];
}];
NSArray *cafFileNames = [directoryContents objectsAtIndexes:cafFileNameIndexes];
```

Then use `cafFileNames` as the underlying data to implement your `UIPickerViewDelegate` / `UIPickerViewDataSource` methods.